# Do we use the word “bedrücken” more than “betrüben” for the verb “distress”?

Tags: meaning, verb, synonym

Do we use the word *bedrücken* more than *betrüben* for the verb *to distress* nowadays and has *betrüben* been abolished?

Comment: I would say "etwas bedrückt mich" but "ich bin betrübt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know where you got the information that *betrüben* had been abolished, but the [following Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bedr%C3%BCcken%2Bbedr%C3%BCckt%2Cbetr%C3%BCben%2Bbetr%C3%BCbt%2Cbek%C3%BCmmern%2Bbek%C3%BCmmert&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28bedr%C3%BCcken%20%2B%20bedr%C3%BCckt%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28betr%C3%BCben%20%2B%20betr%C3%BCbt%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28bek%C3%BCmmern%20%2B%20bek%C3%BCmmert%29%3B%2Cc0) does not support that statement:

[image: Ngram of *betrüben, bekümmern* and *bedrücken*]

All three terms mentioned in [Cryck’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32654) are almost equally frequent in current usage.

The main difference between *betrüben* and *bedrücken* is their hidden meaning. *Trüb* means *cloudy* when referring to something that should be transparent (e.g. glass) or the weather. Thus, *betrüben* is the act of rendering somebody or someone’s feelings cloudy. On the other hand, *drücken* of course means *to press* so something that is *bedrückend* is something that is pressing down on you. Thus, a 16-ton weight would *bedrücken* you but hazy autumn weather would *betrüben* you.

While these nuances exist and are certainly relevant in literature, the two are pretty much synonyms in common usage.

Comment: Dear @Jan  yes, you're right. Thanks for your illustrating diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of those two according to the Duden (a spelling dictionary of the German language):

> [Bedeutung 'bedrücken':](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bedruecken) *auf jemandem lasten; traurig, niedergeschlagen machen*
>   [Bedeutung 'betrüben':](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/betrueben) *traurig machen, traurig stimmen, bekümmern*
>   [Bedeutung 'bekümmern':](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bekuemmern) *betrüben; jemandem Kummer, Sorge bereiten*

In the natural language you can use all of them equally as a translation of '*distress*'.
'*Bedrücken*' and '*bekümmern*' may suppress '*betrüben*' in the long run but it is definitely not replaced/abolished yet. The most common one, based on what I have heard recently, would be '*bekümmern*'.

Comment: According to the linked Duden articles all three verbs are used equally rarely (frequency: 2 of 5)!